# What does this generic type constraint mean in Swift?

Tags: generics, collections, swift, type-constraints

Look at the definition for the overload of `+=` operator in Swift that lets you add elements to a collection:

```
/// Append the elements of rhs to lhs
func +=<T, C : Collection where T == T>(inout lhs: ContiguousArrayBuffer<T>, rhs: C)
                                ^^^^^^
```

What does the `T == T` constraint do? Why do we need it here? It looks like a trivial constraint that's always true.

Comment: Inside this global operator overload function it does look weird...However looking at other places that use this, such as `extension T[] : ArrayType {init<S : Sequence where T == T>(_ s: S)}` It looks like its simply trying to make sure the elements of the argument sequence has the same type as the array you are trying to initialize. I'm not sure how that is enforced through this syntax though..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitions you see in Xcode are not actually a valid Swift code. It is somehow generated on the fly from the original files

I would assume that the `T == T` part is a mistake done by the generator when reducing the original files.

I have tried to define a similar function by myself and `T == T` is not necessary there, it actually sometimes triggers a warning.

Comment: I will elaborate when I am at my desktop.

Comment: I believe you're right. The declarations are generated automatically. 1/ You cannot show the file in Finder. 2/ The symbols are sorted by name with ASCII order. No human being would sort code that way. 3/ A few extensions are empty which suggests they contained code that wasn't parsed/converted. 5/ The declarations are incomplete. For example, no method is declared as `mutating`, which means we should be able to use any method on a constant (but we can't).

Comment: @NicolasBachschmidt There is also some invalid grammar, e.g. `extension T[]`. I belive the `T == T` in this case is there because the function is part of an implementation of a private protocol.